# laravel xss on @yield('section')?

Tags: php, laravel, xss, laravel-blade

Now I have to send the page title to master.blade but it gives XSS on `$request->q` param

template.blade

```
@section('title', $request->q)
```

master.blade

```
<meta property="og:title" content="@yield('title')" />
```

I have already applied

```
@section('title', htmlentities($request->q) )
```

but any better solution?

Answer (score 1):

Usually people do this:

```
<meta property="og:title" content="{{ $title }}">
```

then to set it:

```
@extends("layouts.master", ["title" => $request->q])
```

or:

```
return view("path.to.view", ["title" => $request->q]);
```

Answer (score 0):

My Approach for similar case

```
   <title>@yield("title")</title>
```

and in layout file

```
    @section('title')
    {{ trans('client/parent/list.page_title') }} - {{ trans('app.app_title') }}
    @endsection
```